# How to open socket for Hypnotoad

Tags: perl, sockets, remote-server, mojolicious

Trying to give mojolicious apps a try but having difficulty running them from the server with hypnotoad.

```
[user@server public_html]$ hypnotoad -t app/script/app 
Everything looks good!
[user@server public_html]$ hypnotoad app/script/app 
Can't create listen socket: Address already in use at /usr/local/share/perl5/Mojo/IOLoop.pm line 126.
```

It would appear that everything is in place to be able to start app in hypnotoad but this doesn't work. How would one go about closing whatever is stopping mojolicous from listening on the socket? Or is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Address already is use, the default port is 8080. You can change the port of the Mojo app or kill the app running in 8080.

Comment: How should I check and kill the running app?

Comment: `hypnotoad --stop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `netstat` you can find `PID` of process holding 8080 port, and send `SIGTERM` to stop it,

```
netstat -lntp | perl -nE '/:8080/ or next; say and kill(15, $_) for m|(\d+)/|'
```

Answer (score 3):

To start `hypnotoad` on a different port to the default `8080` I use:

```
#myapp

use Mojolicious::Lite;

# mojo will look for a *.conf with the same name 
# as the application
app->plugin('Config');
app->start;
```

with a config file:

```
# myapp.conf
{
  hypnotoad => {
    listen  => ['http://*:3000'],
    workers => 4
  }
};
```

See the [Perldoc](http://www.mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Server/Hypnotoad) for the various config options.

Comment: I've been using clones of the same Mojolicious app running, using hypnotoad on different ports. They're all behind nginx with proxy_pass. One thing I've found is that I need to spell out exactly where to find the config: `my $config_file = /home/hbarnard/psbl/datamap.conf ;` otherwise there's some confusion that I haven't sorted out yet.